# Piwik installation not working

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, apache, matomo

I have set up a Piwik server and added tracking code in one of my website.EX:- (http://***.mobolt.com)
I am seeing no JS error on http://***.mobolt.com
And when I am hitting http://***.mobolt.com , I am seeing Logs in Piwik server (/var/log/apache2/access.log), But somehow nothing is getting saved in my piwik database.

Following are the logs I am seeing in Piwik Server(/var/log/apache2/access.log):-

```
49.206.176.75 - - [16/Jul/2013:10:58:30 +0000] "GET /analytics//piwik.js HTTP/1.1" 200 9583 "https://*****.mobolt.com/show_job_page?job_id=603" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/25.0.1364.160 Chrome/25.0.1364.160 Safari/537.22"
49.206.176.75 - - [16/Jul/2013:10:58:30 +0000] "GET /analytics//piwik.php?action_name=Zachry's%20Careers&idsite=1&rec=1&r=733748&h=16&m=28&s=31&url=https%3A%2F%2F*****.mobolt.com%2Fshow_job_page%3Fjob_id%3D603&urlref=https%3A%2F%2F*****.mobolt.com%2Flist_job_page&_id=4fbabd896c0de337&_idts=1373966839&_idvc=3&_idn=0&_refts=0&_viewts=1373969542&pdf=0&qt=1&realp=0&wma=1&dir=0&fla=1&java=1&gears=0&ag=0&cookie=1&res=1600x900&gt_ms=340 HTTP/1.1" 200 437 "https://*****.mobolt.com/show_job_page?job_id=603" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.22 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/25.0.1364.160 Chrome/25.0.1364.160 Safari/537.22"
49.206.176.75 - - [16/Jul/2013:10:58:38 +0000] "POST /analytics/index.php?date=2013-07-16&module=Live&action=getLastVisitsStart&idSite=1&period=day HTTP/1.1" 200 416 "http://piwik.mobolt.com/analytics/index.php?module=CoreHome&action=index&idSite=1&period=day&date=today" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0"
```

Can someone please help me here ?

Comment: Are there any PHP error messages generated? Do you know where your system logs PHP error messages to? Perhaps /var/log/apache2/error.log? Is the database connection set up correctly, i.e. username, password, dbname and such in /analytics/config/config.ini.php?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed some possible issues:

GET /analytics//piwik.js => Shouldn't this be "/analytics//piwik.js", you have 2 "/"

GET /analytics//piwik.php?action_name=Zachry's%20Careers => Same as above, you have 2 "/", also I don't think the single quote "'" char is valid for query strings

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A ( search for "reserved      = gen-delims / sub-delims"

It's hard to debug for you without other info.